# How to visualize revisions graph in IntelliJ (Mercurial)

Tags: intellij-idea, mercurial, revision-graph

I am new to IntelliJ and simply can't find the revisions graph for a Mercurial project in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually found it myself and it is a little tricky to find.

Go to `View > Tool Windows > Changes`

or click <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> in Mac

There you will find a tab called **Log** which gives you the graphical view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need the plugin [hg4idea](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3370?pr=) although I don't remember it having a nice pretty graph of commits, just a history.

Try [sourcetree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/) or [tortoisehg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), for a graph.